# JSXC.start have some delay

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xampp, chat, ejabberd

I am using jsxc for chatting. When I login I am starting jsxc with `jsxc.start(username, password);` in few secounds some delay is there, no html events are working. The whole UI is hanging for few secounds.

- My jsxc version **jsxc v3.2.1**.
- My project is written with **angularjs and c#**.
- Each user have **750 - 800 buddylist**.
- I have **no error in console**.
- If i remove jsxc start from my project there is no delay. same like that, if I reduce the buddylist to 100 then also delay is not there.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this `setTimeout(function(){jsxc.start(username, password);}, 1000);`